# what is wrong with "long long " in this c program?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    long long sum=2,x=1,y=2,z=0,i;
    for(i=2;i<200000;i++)
    {
        z=x+y;
        y=y+z;
        x=z;
        if(z%2==0)
            sum+=z;
if(y%2==0)
sum+=y;
    }
    printf("%lld",sum);
    getch();
}
```

**addition of even Fibonacci numbers.** It is working properly for i<200000 but when I increased limit by one more digit it is showing negative answer. I have tried "unsigned long long" and "long long int " but i didn't get correct answer.. please help me out...

Comment: What does `printf("%lld");` mean?

Comment: `printf("%lld")` is missing a `long long` parameter. (And, less critically, a new line.)

Comment: Your compiler should have warned you about `printf("%lld");`.  Enable all warnings or get a new compiler.

Comment: It's _not_ working properly for 20,000,000. As far as I can see, your `z` overflows for `i == 47` when `long long` is 64-bits wide.

Comment: Are you sure you want to sum even fibo number for i<2000000 ?

Comment: You said "It is working properly for i<20000000", but in your program you have used i<2000000 which is incorrect.. What are you actually saying?

Comment: sorry I have typed incorrectly. I have corrected them.. it is showing correct answer untill 200000  but afterwards it starts to generate negative number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should print sum:

```
printf("%lld\n", sum);
```

`printf("%lld");` will print garbage value

If this is not the problem, then you can't actually sum even Fibonacci number for `i<2000000`.

Because:

For `i<20000` your program will give you a sum which is actually a **8359** digit number. Now what about `i<2000000`? This will take huge amount of time and memory. I think you are not actually doing this. This is not feasible to do.

**And finally, your program is not generating Fibonacci number at all**

Comment: I noticed this too, but the OP did say it's printing correct numbers until `20000000` which implies he might have the print statement right in his code, but he might have just written it incorrectly on StackOverflow.

Comment: @SpencerGrantDoak, His program is correct for "i<20000000" and incorrect for i<2000000. This is not good, right?

Comment: Well yes, that is not good. According to his question, that's the issue he's trying to resolve. The OP says the output is correct for the first 20,000,000 iterations.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience. I have mistype d in the program and missed printf("lld\n",sum) in the question. It  is working for i<299999 but afterwards it shows negative number as a answer.

Comment: @VasanthHegde, I don't think so. Your program will give you correct output only for i<49. For i=49, sum=54730748958638792258 this will overflow.

Comment: @AerofoilKite, then what should I do to get sum of even Fibonacci number for i<4_million in c?

Comment: Do you want 4_million Fibonacci number or Fibonacci numbers which are less then 4_million?

Answer (score 2):

You said the code works until you ask for `i < 20000000`. Here is what I think is happening: I believe you are encountering an overflow error. I understand that you switched from `signed long long` to `unsigned long long` which does double the possible range of the numbers, but even still, 20 million iterations of fibonacci is a lot even when the sum is only of the even numbers.

If you truly need an accurate solution out to such a large term as 20 million, you will not be able to rely on standard C. You will have to find an alternative library. You should search for a library which handles **Arbitrary Precision**.

I would recommend the **[GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library (GMP)](https://gmplib.org/)**. More details about this library can be found on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multiple_Precision_Arithmetic_Library). GMP can offer you precision which is only limited by the available RAM. However, bear in mind that large calculations come at a cost of large processing times.

I conquered a similar problem to this in Java using Java's `BigInteger` class, but the heart of the issue is all the same. You just need arbitrary precision.

Answer (score 1):

`printf()` should be changed to

```
printf("%lld\n",sum);
```

The range of `unsinged long long` is

```
0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615
```

and the range of `long long` is

```
–9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
```

IN your case the output will lead to integer overflow so you get negative value when you add one more digit the checking value(20000000) in the `for` loop which will eventually lead to undefined behavior.